# Generating an SVG rectangle with dashed fill lines

Tags: jquery, css, svg, dimple.js

I have a rectangle made with dimpleJS and need the box filled with dashed lines instead of a solid color. Is this possible using svg, css and/or jquery?  The rectangle is below.

```
<rect id="dimple-not-working-on-an-associate-s-degree-2008-not-working-on-an-associate-s-degree---" class="dimple-series-0 dimple-bar dimple-not-working-on-an-associate-s-degree dimple-2008 dimple-not-working-on-an-associate-s-degree dimple-custom-series-bar dimple-custom-format-1" x="183.5" y="128.4" width="18" height="141.6" opacity="0.8" style="fill: rgb(92, 186, 230); stroke: rgb(77, 156, 192);" fill="#5cbae6" stroke="rgb(77, 156, 192)"></rect>
```

Comment: fill it with a pattern. In the pattern draw whatever dashed lines you want.

Comment: how do you fill it with a pattern? is that an svg or css thing? thanks a ton

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Robert mentions in the comments, what you need to do is using a [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern) to fill the rectangle. The steps are easy:

- Define a pattern in the SVG
- Inside the pattern, "draw" whatever you want to be the pattern. For example, you want dashed lines, so you would do a line that occupies only part of the pattern, so when it is repeated it will look dashed.
- Set the attribute `patternUnits` to "userSpaceOnUse"so the pattern will occupy the whole element in which it is applied (as it would do with a background-repeat).
- Apply the pattern in the `fill`  attribute by referencing its id (e.g. `fill="url(#pattern-id)"`)

Here you can see a demo working:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="lines" height="10" width="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <line x1="0" y1="4" x2="5" y2="4" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="url(#lines)" />
</svg>
```